# Retake certification associate developer Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Unfortunately, I didn't pass the M2 Associate Developer exam :( with a score at 63.93%.
So, i'll retake it.

My question is : it will be the same questions or it will be different from the first exam ?

Thank you by advance for your answers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question for the exam come from a pool of questions. So you won't get the same questions again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150627)

Comment: @ManashviBirla how does this not answer the question? I'm clearly stating that it won't be the same questions

Comment: Thank you for this answer :) let's work more then !